# Flashrom and the RaspberryPi

Tags: gpio

I'm in the process of needing to flash an EEPROM and since I've found that flashrom works with the Pi I want to do it on it. I have flashrom installed, and have the EEPROM pins connected to the right GPIO pins but now what do it do? Is there any guides you can recommend?

Comment: What kind of EEPROM? SPI or I2C?

Comment: http://www.jotschi.de/Technik/2012/09/07/raspberry-pi-25lc010a-eeprom-howto.html ???